# Deselecting a data with different column value

Tags: sql-server-2008

Hi guys I've got this table structure

```
 field 1                  field 2
---------------------------------------------
    1                        1
    1                        2
    2                        1
```

Then I want it to be like this when selecting Key `Field2 = 1`

```
 field 1                  field 2
---------------------------------------------
   2                         1
```

I don't want to return `field1 = 1` because It contains different values field1 IN (1,2)

Thanks you so much.

Comment: `SELECT field_1, field_2 FROM table WHERE field_2 = 1 AND field_1 != 1`

Answer (score 1):

Your post seems unclear because I think you mixed up column names in certain parts of your description. However, judging by your sample output, I'm going to assume you mean the following:

> Select rows from the table where `field2` contains identical values for the same `field1`.

If you only need to output `field1` and `field2`, you could do the following:

```
SELECT field1, MAX(field2) AS field2
FROM atable
GROUP BY field1
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT field2) = 1
```

You can omit `DISTINCT` if your table cannot hold duplicate pairs of `(field1, field2)`.

However, if there are more columns in the table and some or all of them need to be returned too, you could first just get the `field1` values like above, then join that row set back to `atable` to get complete rows, like this:

```
SELECT t.*  /* or specify the necessary columns explicitly */
FROM atable AS t
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT field1
    FROM atable
    GROUP BY field1
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT field2) = 1
  ) s ON t.field1 = s.field1
```

Again, `DISTINCT` can be omitted, as explained above.

Since you are using SQL Server 2008, you could also use windowed aggregating. If your table doesn't contain duplicates of `(field1, field2)`, you could use the following:

```
;
WITH counted AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    cnt = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY field1)
  FROM atable
)
SELECT
  field1,
  field2,
  …
FROM counted
WHERE cnt = 1
```

But if the duplicates are allowed, you'll need to use a slightly different approach, because there's no windowing counterpart for `COUNT(DISTINCT …)`. Here's what you could try:

```
;
WITH counted AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    f2min = MIN(field2) OVER (PARTITION BY field1),
    f2max = MAX(field2) OVER (PARTITION BY field1)
  FROM atable
)
SELECT
  field1,
  field2,
  …
FROM minmaxed
WHERE f2min = f2max
```

That is, you are getting the minimum and the maximum value of `field2` for every `field1` value. Then you are filtering out rows where `f2min` is not the same as `f2max`, because that would imply that there are different `field2` values in the group.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field_2 = 1 AND field_1 <> 1
```